# Is it possible to use Scada software itself to monitor its internals for diagnostics and performance assesment?

Tags: java, scada

If possible, is it really feasible in terms of resource consumption and accuracy of gathered data?

Comment: Sounds non-sensical. Suppose the system goes down. What is the good of monitoring something with itself?  The point of a tool like NAGIOS is to monitor infrastructure, and prove that services and networks are up.  I would gather my data with NAGIOS and then provide views in the SCADA MMI screens that reflect the data captured by NAGIOS.

Answer (score 1):

It certainly is possible, and I think most modern SCADA packages offer information regarding system health and performance...Wonderware and Citect come to mind.  I wouldn't think the internal monitoring would produce much extra overhead.

However, particularly for larger systems, I'm of the opinion that I rather let the SCADA software handle SCADA related tasks and use another tool for monitoring system/network performance.  Tools like Nagios for example have a long track record and were built for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

We have the same problem in Scada-LTS because it offers special data source "internal data source" to monitor scada but I'm not sure this is correct approach  because it creates background thread  monitoring. This creates overhead consuming more resource.